# How to use "struct" with currying "Func"?

Tags: c#, currying

"Curry" interests me very much so I try to incorporate it into C# "Func".
There is a simple exercise to read a few positive values then sum, count, and average this series. The following list is the 1st trial:

```
Func<int, Func<int, int>> CurriedSum = x => y => x + y;//Declare curryied sum
Func<int, int> CurriedCount = x => x + 1;//Declare counting
Console.Write("Please input the first number in a series: ");//Prompt
int inputValue = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//User's input
int sum = inputValue;//original sum = 1st value
int count = CurriedCount(0);//count from 0
do
{
    Console.Write("Please input the next number in a series (0 will exit):");//Prompt
    inputValue = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//User's input
    if (inputValue > 0)//Accept positive number only
    {
        sum = CurriedSum(inputValue)(sum);//Call curried function to sum
        count = CurriedCount(count);//Call function to count
        Console.Write($"=> Sum of {count} numbers is {sum}.");//Output
        Console.WriteLine($" Mean is {(float)resultInt/count}.");//Output
    }
} while (inputValue > 0);//loop until 0 or any negative number
```

This trial works. However, the following 2nd trial fails:

```
internal struct MyStruct
{
    public int Sum;
    public int Count;
    public float Mean;
}//located above static void Main(string[] args)

//Func<int, Func<int, MyStruct>> CurriedSumMean = x => y =>//wrong
Func<int, Func<MyStruct, MyStruct>> CurriedSumMean = x => y =>//*correct*
{
    MyStruct result;//no need to initialize
    //result.Sum = x + y;//wrong
    //result.Count++;//Error here!
    result.Sum = x + y.Sum;//*correct*
    result.Count = y.Count + 1;//*correct*
    result.Mean = result.Sum / result.Count;
    return result;
};//Calculate and return curried sum, counting and average
MyStruct series;//Declare a series
Console.Write("Please input the first number in a series: ");//Prompt
inputValue = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//User's input
series.Sum = inputValue;//original sum = 1st value
series.Count = 1;//count from 1
series.Mean = inputValue;//original average = 1st value
do
{
    Console.Write("Please input the next number in a series (0 will exit):");//Prompt
    inputValue = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//User's input
    if (inputValue > 0)//Accept positive number only
    {
        series = CurriedSumMean(inputValue)(series);//*it works!*
        Console.Write($"=> Sum of {series.Count} numbers is {series.Sum}.");//Output
        Console.WriteLine($" Mean is {series.Mean}.");//Output
    }
} while (inputValue > 0);//loop until 0 or any negative number
```

Two errors are found by Visual Studio 2017. One is result.Count++; defined within the curried function function CurriedSumMean. The other error is series = CurriedSumMean(inputValue)(series).

How can I correctly use both "struct" and "Func", especially currying?
Thanks a lot for your assistance.

Comment: @ojlovecd & l33t, both you are right! I try to initialize the object "result" and it works. However, I change the curried function to "Func<int, Func<MyStruct, MyStruct>> CurriedSumMean = x => y =>" to accept MyStruct for series. Therefore, "series = CurriedSumMean(inputValue)(series);" has no error. Also "result.Count++;" must change to "result.Count = y.Count + 1;"

Comment: @vasily.sib, you are right! I try to keep original statement "MyStruct result;" and it works. No need to initialize the struct. However, the Func must be modified to "Func<int, Func<MyStruct, MyStruct>>", it means the first MyStruct is the output type of last call, and the second MyStruct is the output type of this call. Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to initialize the object before you use it

```
MyStruct result = new MyStruct();
```

you can't convert a struct object to an integer. I suppose you should use series.Sum here

```
series = CurriedSumMean(inputValue)(series.Sum);
```

Comment: `MyStruct` is a `struct` - no need to initialize

Comment: `MyStruct` is a `struct` - need to initialize. This is the correct answer.

Comment: @l33t, why do you need to initialize? For `MyStruct result1;` and `MyStruct result2 = new MyStruct();` this structures will be exactly the same (I mean `result1.Sum == result2.Sum && result1.Count == result2.Count && result1.Mean == result2.Mean`).

Comment: @vasily.sib: You are both getting hung up on the struct-ness, but that's not what's relevant. **All local variables must be assigned to before they are read from**.  All fields and array elements are assigned their default values; they do not need to be assigned to explicitly. This is true regardless of whether the type is a value type or a reference type

Comment: That said, there used to be a bug in the C# semantic analyzer where a local variable that is a struct that had only private members was automatically marked as initialized, because the semantic analyzer actually checks "are all this structs members initialized before they are used?" and it skipped inaccessible members. I don't know if that bug has been fixed in more recent builds of C#.

Comment: @EricLippert, sorry, I can't understand. You are talking about some bug in C# semantic analyzer which cause invalid local struct variables initialization? Can you point me to some article, where it is described, or, even better, show me some code sample at dotnetfiddle? I will be very grateful.

Comment: @EricLippert, sorry, just found this by myself, thanks for pointing me.